# Force creation of bind mount in docker-compose

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-compose

I am trying to make a neo4j container use host system directories for `data` and `logs` using `docker-compose`. My compose file looks like this

```
neo4j:
  image: neo4j:3.5.6
  ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:7474:7474"
    - "127.0.0.1:7473:7473"
    - "127.0.0.1:7687:7687"
  environment:
    NEO4J_AUTH: "none"
  volumes:
    - "~/neo4j/data:/data"
    - "~/neo4j/logs:/logs"
```

However, it only works for the `logs` directory, for the `data` directory, the container keeps its own volume. The binds section of `docker inspect` looks like this

```
"Binds": [
     "/home/rbusche/neo4j/logs:/logs:rw",
     "6f989b981c12a252776404343044b6678e0fac48f927e80964bcef409ab53eef:/data:rw"
],
```

Peculiar enough it works when I use `docker run` and specify the volume there. The [`neo4j` Dockerfile](https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j-publish/blob/af59f1d6a03f87c0f391c3fbdb482ccb0cd65b59/3.5.6/community/Dockerfile) declares both `data` and `logs` as container volumes. This there any way to force `docker-compose` to override those?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but with no success. For me it works as it should. I also started it without volumes (so that is creates its own) and then started it again with the volumes and it correctly created them. The fact that they are declared as volumes in the Dockerfile has no influence on the behaviour. Could you double check that you use this version of the docker-compose?

Comment: did you try with the absolute path?

Comment: Try checking if you havent created some weirdly named volume by mistake... What's the output of `docker volume ls`

Answer (score 2):

After removing the volume `6f989b981c12a252776404343044b6678e0fac48f927e80964bcef409ab53eef` and the container associated with it, it works as expected. It seems like the container was clinging to a volume it created on a previous start.